# installing rJava error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, r, ubuntu

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             linux-gnu
>   system         x86_64, linux-gnu
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          0.2
>   year           2013
>   month          09
>   day            25
>   svn rev        63987
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

**hi i get this error in my Rstudio console, and i tried already installing Java in my terminal and downloading the 64 bit packages that they give me here ->
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

but i didn't find out how to install them anyway, i tried extracting a couple of times but i don't get the point of doing that

the error is this one:**

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
4 warnings
/usr/bin/jar fc JRI.jar org libjri.so
make[2]: se sale del directorio «/tmp/RtmpNYWc6R/R.INSTALL47403365e0ea/rJava/jri/src»
rm -f libjri.so
cp src/libjri.so libjri.so
/usr/bin/javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -classpath src/JRI.jar -d examples examples/rtest.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: examples/rtest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 warnings
/usr/bin/javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -classpath src/JRI.jar -d examples examples/rtest2.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: examples/rtest2.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 warnings
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/tmp/RtmpNYWc6R/R.INSTALL47403365e0ea/rJava/jri»
installing via 'install.libs.R' to /home/samuel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rJava
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/samuel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
Error: loading failed
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/samuel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpoAN8yK/downloaded_packages’
```